# Predictor for the sum of random variables

Tags: forecasting, predictor

I have a random variable Y, which is a sum of N random variables
$$Y=\sum_{i=1}^N Y_i$$

Some of the $Y_i$ may be positively or negatively correlated to each other and in fact many of them are.

I have another set of random variables $X_1, ..., X_N$ where $X_i$ is a predictor of $Y_i$. I am now trying to use these predictors to predict $Y$, simply taking

$$X=\sum_{i=1}^N X_i$$

I found that the $X_i$ are decent predictors of the $Y_i$. The correlation between $X_i$ and $Y_i$ is reasonably high and if I do a linear regression between $X_i$ and $Y_i$ I get slopes close to 1 and $R^2$ between 5% and 10%. However the prediction quality of the sum is much worse, i.e. $X$ is a much worse predictor of $Y$ than the $X_i$ of the $Y_i$.

The reason must lie in the high correlation between the $Y_i$. Some of the $Y_i$ are highly correlated negatively and of similar dimension, i.e. $Y_i + Y_j $ may be small compared to the absolute value of $Y_i, Y_j$ and it seems that the $X_i$ are good at predicting the total level of the $Y_i$, but much less these sums.

Is there any better way of constructing a predictor of $Y$ using my $X_i$ than simply taking the sum?

Comment: Why not predict each $Y_i$ and then sum?

Comment: well this is what I am doing? Maybe this is not clear from my question but each $X_i$ is a predictor of $Y_i$ and then I just sum the $X_i$

Comment: You sum $X_i$ then predict $Y$ from $X$, which is not the same as predicting each $Y_i$ from $X_i$, and then summing.

Comment: for my application it is the same. I only care about how well $X$ predicts $Y$. I first compute my predictor $X_i$ for each $Y_i$ and then take the sum of these.

Comment: Well, 5% $R^2$ is actually very low, so it's not surprising that when you then sum all your estimates you have a rather bad prediction...

Comment: that is true, but in the application I am looking at 5% is decent. The problem is thatt after summing the predictors up I get R^2 less than 0.1% and regression coefficients close to 0.

Comment: Why is $R^2$ a relevant metric?  By using it, you are not making a direct or fair comparison of the two methods.  Due to the anticorrelation, the variance of the sum of the $Y_i$ may be much smaller than that of the individual $Y_i$ and therefore, *even if you could predict the sum more accurately than you can predict individual $Y_i,$* you would likely still see a reduction in $R^2.$  Could you provide comparisons of the typical sizes of the residuals in each model?

Comment: Are the Xis independent?